# For a given class in C++, is it possible to have, as a private variable, a vector of objects of the same class?

Tags: c++, vector

It has been a long time since I did any C++ programming, and I would highly appreciate it if anyone can guide me with creating a Node class that has one of its private variable a list (or vector) of objects of the Node class.

I am hoping to create a class structure as such:

```
class Node {
private:
  string ID;
  vector < Node > list;
public:
  Node();
  void some_Function();
};
```

Is this the right approach? Is it possible for a class to have one of its private members as a list of objects of the same class type?

Comment: What you can have is a `vector<Node*>`.

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>` is even better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot.

When you define an object of type `vector<T>`, `T` must be a complete type, which it's not until the end of the class definition.

Some compilers will accept the code anyway (they'll accept a vector of some incomplete type), but it's not allowed by the C++ standard.

Comment: Can we have `vector<Node*>` as mentioned in the comments?

Comment: @Saksham: Yes -- `Node *` is a complete type, even when `Node` is not.

Comment: Ohh yes. now I realize that I knew this.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I used vector <Node *>, and it works great. Thank you all of you for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly in a single class. But you can use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which is something that's meant specifically for something like this.

You'll have a template base class and a derived class that is templated on it's own type. The base class is then free to define other generics (like a `vector`) based on the derived class. Sample code below:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename Derived>
class Base{
    vector<Derived> nodes;
public:
    void TestInsert(const Derived& der){
        nodes.push_back(der);
    }
    void TestPrintSize(){
        printf("NUM %d\n", nodes.size());
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>{};

int main(){
    Derived1 der1, der2;
    der2.TestInsert(der1);
    der2.TestPrintSize();
}
```

Comment: This is a beautiful CRTP solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, either by using pointers or by introducing a helper class:

```
class NodeVector;

class Node {
  private:
    string ID;
    NodeVector *vect;

  public:
    Node() : vect(new NodeVector) { }
    // Don't forget other constructors & destructor because you allocate vect
};

class NodeVector {
  public:
    std::list< Node >;
};
```

Comment: Your example uses a pointer *and* introduces a helper class. So, what's the point of the helper class?

Comment: First, the alternative would be to allocate the pointer to each node separately, which is N allocation for N "other" nodes. If you replace list with vector in this example you'd have a continuous chunk of memory for all "other" nodes. Second, explicit allocation here happens only in the constructors and deallocation in destructor, once per lifetime of "this" node, and not every time the list of "other" nodes changes, so less chance for a bug. Finally, this puts a decent portion of Node functionality, namely keeping track of "other" nodes, into a separate class, which is good for design.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jerry said. You cannot.

This is not the same as

```
class node {
    int data;
    node *next;
}
```

With node *, the compiler only needs to know the size of the pointer. But for `vector<T>` the compiler needs to know the size of your class `T`, which is not defined until the end of the class definition.

Comment: Sorry, Jerry. I cannot add my comments to your answer as my reputation is too low. Thus, a separate answer.