# Converting to template class (NODES)

Tags: c++

```
template <class Type>
class Node
{
public:
        Node ()
        {
        }
        Node (Type x, Node* nd)
        {
             data = x;
             next = nd;
        }
        Node (Type x)
        {
            data = x;
            next = NULL;

        }
        ~Node (void)
        {

        }

        Node (const Node* & nd)
        {
            data = nd->data;
            next = nd->next;
        }

        Node & Node::operator = (const Node* & nd)
        {
            data = nd->data;
            next = nd->next;
        }

        T data;
        Node* next;


};
```

Do I replace every Node* with

```
Node*<Type>
```

I tried replacing it and tried running something like

```
Node* temp = myq.head;
```

but it says argument list for class template "Node" is missing. I'm not really sure how to work with Templates when I need the Node class itself being part of it

Comment: what's `myq.head`? how is it defined?

Comment: my.qhead is just another Node object, well technically it should be. But now it really isn't because myq.head won't get defined in the first place

Comment: We had a similar question a few days ago, watch here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19034786/1529139

Comment: That's exactly what I asked in my question, and Node<Type>* did not work

Comment: if you show how `myq.head` is defined, will be helpful

Comment: Node* head; is how it's defined but there's an error on that as well

Comment: `Node* head;` is not valid code, `Node` is a template, a type name must be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every declaration of Node will need a type in <>.

For

```
Node* temp = myq.head;
```

it depends on what myq.head is defined as. If it's defined as Node<int>* then temp also has to be defined as Node<int>* temp. You always have to have the <> with template objects.

If you wanted to have Node* without knowing the type, you could use inheritance. Have a templated TypedNode class that inherits from a non-template Node class. You would be able to pass all those TypeNode<> objects around with Node*, but you wouldn't be able to get the value of the nodes back out without knowing their type.

I don't recommend this but If you *really* want to make nodelists with mixed types you'll need to track the types by either

1. Include an enum type in the base class that defines the type stored in the node, and define typedNode for each class, setting the enum in it's constructor, or returning it from a virtual method.
2. RTTI, Run Time Type Information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information